# Is it ethical to apply for another job after 6 months to negotiate a raise?

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise

My coworkers say I should ask for a raise at my 6 months of work so I think I might. This is the first time I'm doing it so I was thinking if it would be okay to apply for another job (one that is reputable at paying a lot) and using that as a negotiation?

Comment: Are you talking about using the act of merely applying (or saying you did) as some sort of imagined leverage? Or are you referring to actually getting an offer and using that offer to get a counter offer?

Comment: I assumed we had a general question on the title question but we apparently don't so that would be good to have on the site. But the body of this question is something altogether different, particularly given the time OP has been with the company. I'm changing the title for now to match the body.

Comment: If you get a higher offer, would you really want to use that to get a raise after only 6 months at your current job, or would you just take their offer instead, and say goodbye to the place you've been at for only half a year?

Answer (score 5):

If you use another work as an argument why you should receive an increase in your current job there is a significant risk that you will lose out. Threatning to leave if you don't get what you want, as this will be perceived, can be taken as a lack of faith in the company and a will to leave, among other. If you decide to keep working at the company your reputation and relation with your superiors will likely be soured.

A company is primarily interested in what you can bring to them in term of experience, output etc. If you are a key-member with special knowledge, skills etc. that are key in order for the company to continue and not come to a grinding halt, yes then maybe that would be a valid tactic. Once. Creating that kind of bus-factor is a sure way of being replaced or made obsolete, but there are scores of questions that can tell you more on that.

**TLDR:** Being a rank and file employee this will most likely not work, and any threat you make that you don't carry through will harm your reputation and will damage your relation with the company.

Answer (score 3):

This is a one-trick. It could work the first time, provided the employer wants to keep you. The second time, this won't work anymore and any leaving threats will be considered empty.

Regarding ethics, there is nothing wrong with looking for a better opportunity at any point of your career. Looking for jobs is a perfecty normal activity. However consider the amount of time involved : several interviews that you will have to prepare, several interviewers, process downtime ... Your idea looks like a huge amount of time invested for a very uncertain amount of return.

Finally please consider the risk of coming to your boss and saying "Boss, company Y offered me 10-15% more, I haven't even worked a year, raise me." If you are not critical, the boss could just say "OK, please leave and thanks for your 6 months".

If you really feel underpaid, start with a benchmark of your colleagues and the market as a negotiation basis. This will take way less time, while being perfectly ethical.

Comment: I think a 10-15% raise doesn't worth the risks of a new job (what if it won't pass? You will fall between two chairs to the ground).

Comment: This is true. In my opinion, OP's position is risky. On the other hand, imagine an employee asking for 30% raise after 6 months, what would you answer him as the boss/HR ? 10-15% after 6 months is already very significant.

Comment: It depends on, how was it negotiated at the beginning of his employment. If we talked about a raise after the end of his trial period, and his work is really worthy, I would do on the original plans. If there wasn't any, and his work worths its price, and it doesn't produce tension with other employees, then maybe I would say ok, but probably not so much. Most probably I would say "half year isn't enough for this, after another half year it will be ok".

Comment: You did hit the nail on this as it is most definitely a one shot deal.  The OP had best be fully prepared to be shown the door too.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of questions for you to consider.

1. Do **YOU** think you are underpaid/deserve more?
2. If they didn't offer you any more money, would you leave?
3. Are you happy at your current role? Is it good for your development/progression?
4. Are the other roles you're looking for at your level (i.e. Junior/Senior roles)?
5. Is money your main goal?

You have only been there 6 months. I think that's too early to ask for a raise unless it was expressed there would be a review when you joined, or you have done something exceptional at the company. If you threaten to leave, you have to be willing to leave, otherwise your threat carries no weight.

Consider your career progression too. Yes, currently it doesn't help pay the bills, but look at the longer term goal of your career. If you are solely after the money (and there's nothing wrong with that) then go ahead and apply. Just be cautious, if you have several 6 month stints on your CV, it will put people off you. Of course, you can justify the odd move, but not many.

Answer (score 2):

#### Never believe the "good ideas" of your co-workers in your relation with your bosses.

Do you think they really want you to have a higher wage?

No, not this is what they want. They want to use you as a "battering ram" without taking any risk themselves:

[image]

It is particularly bad to threaten your boss with leaving, with negotiations with other companies, on the spot after the end of your trial period. Even if you want a higher salary, don't mention that you are negotiating with other companies.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested multiple times on this SE, you should almost always refuse raise offers while leaving. Trying to trick your employer into giving you one is a very bad move.

Two things could happen, according to company needs:

**If you're considered valuable** the company will try to keep you on board, and offer you that raise. The main consequence here is that you will start a process where you'll be made less and less valuable, in the case you actually leave in the future. You may also lose a lot of reputation for wanting to leave, and even be let go in the future.

**If you're considered easily replaceable** (this is probably the case as you are just 6 months into the job) your boss will thank you for your work and tell you to pack your things. If you then back down you'll look like a fool, and actually leaving for another job will be your only remaining option.

If you really think you deserve a raise, just ask for it. Prepare facts and datas for WHY they should give you a raise, and if you're worthy (and the company can afford it) you'll get it.